# Meteor, questions about verification email

Tags: email, meteor, iron-router

I have some questions about sending verification email and popup dialogs.

- How to change verification email content? I have to add text in Russian
- How to avoid auto logging in after user registration? I would like to forbid user logging in if the email address is not verified.
- How to change content and style of popup dialogs, like Email verified?

I'm using *iron-router, accounts-** packages/

Comment: The first question is no longer actual: the answer is in the [documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_emailtemplates)
But second is actual! I tried to delete `this.setUserId(result.id);` from `password_server.js` - same result. I set `Accounts._preventAutoLogin = true;` and no result too...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To change the verification email follow the template used at : https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/accounts-password/email_templates.js

#### Customizing the email template

E.g (taken from the url above), there's lots to customise.

```
Accounts.emailTemplates.verifyEmail = {
   subject: function(user) {
      return "How to verify email address on " + Accounts.emailTemplates.siteName;
   },
   text: function(user, url) {
       var greeting = (user.profile && user.profile.name) ?
           ("Hello " + user.profile.name + ",") : "Hello,";
       return greeting + "\n"
              + "\n"
              + "To verify your account email, simply click the link below.\n"
              + "\n"
              + url + "\n"
              + "\n"
              + "Thanks.\n";
   }
}
```

#### How to avoid auto logging in after user registration

To register don't use `Accounts.createUser` on the client side. Use a method/call to proxy your message to the server

Client side

```
Meteor.call("registerMe", username, password, function(err, result) {

});
```

Server Side:

```
Meteor.methods({
    registerMe: function(username, password) {
        return Accounts.createUser({username: username, password: password});
    }
});
```

#### How to change content and style of popup dialogs, like Email verified?

You can customize accounts-ui stuff by removing accounts-ui from your project and adding in an unstyled one, followed by adding in styles seperately

```
meteor remove accounts-ui
meteor add accounts-ui-unstyled
meteor add less
```

Then use the `.less` file at https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/accounts-ui/login_buttons.less into your project and customize it to your preferences.

Comment: On your second answer ("How to avoid auto logging in after user registration"), can you give more details? If you're using built-in Meteor accounts packages, as OP is, it's not as simple as editing your own code per your examples; it seems like you have to hack into the packages themselves.

Comment: @Zach It can be done with normal accounts-password only if you want. The trick is registering from the server instead of the client, with the same code. From the server it wont log you in, from the client it will. I use a method call 'registerMe' to make the call on the server

Comment: @Akshat I have used your registerMe method to great effect. How would I then trigger the sending of a verification email from the server passing userId and token?

Answer (score 4):

```
Accounts.validateLoginAttempt(function(type){

    if(type.user && type.user.emails && !type.user.emails[0].verified )
        throw new Meteor.Error(100002, "email not verified" );
    return true;
});
```

Comment: this throws a wrong credential error each time, any ideas?

Comment: Not working..This seems like the straightforward approach but it appears that the Accounts.sendVerificationEmail() is calling validateLoginAttempt and this will block the creation of the user before even sending the mail...